# hjson: why does close brace have to be on a separate line?

Tags: hjson

This works: (**update**: but not as I was thinking! it actually sets b = "c, d: e")

```
a: [
   { b: c, d: e 
   }
]
```

and this works:

```
a: [
   { "b": "c", "d": "e" }
]
```

But this doesn't work.  What about the [hjson definition](https://hjson.org/syntax.html) disallows the closing brace at the end of the line?

```
a: [
   { b: c, d: e }
]

Found ']' where a key name was expected
(check your syntax or use quotes if the key name
 includes {}[],: or whitespace): line 3 column 1 (char 23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hjson a string without quotes is terminated by the newline, so your closing brace gets eaten by the quoteless string.

When you write

```
{ b: c, d: e 
}
```

you are saying, give me a string that contains `"c, d: e"`.

You need to use either quotes

```
{ b: "c", d: "e" }
```

or

```
{ 
  b: c
  d: e
}
```